Copying vim colors from older (vim7.4) to vim8
I moved to a host which has vim8, from one which had vim7.4, the syntax highlight colors are all different (for C code) with colorscheme default!
So, I tried to check the :highlight groups on older, and added lines like this in ~/.vimrc
au BufWinEnter *.c,*.h highlight Constant ctermfg=9
...

But this doesn't seem to take effect when I open .c files in vim !
When I run the command manually with
:highlight Constant ctermfg=9, I see that the color changes for constants
but when I open a new file, again, the default colors seem to be in effect!!
How do I make my highlight changes persist?
Note: this is vim run in terminal (xfce)

To ensure that my custom syntax highlighting settings persist when I open new files in Vim, I did the following:
Get the plugin:
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim

Open Vim and run the following commands to install the plugins:
:source ~/.vimrc
:PlugInstall

My ~/.vimrc looks like this:
" Ensure syntax highlighting is enabled
syntax on

" Specify the encoding and file formats
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf-8,latin1

" Set the number of spaces a <Tab> in the file counts for
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

" Enable line numbers
set number

" Set a dark background
set background=dark

" Custom color scheme with black background and green text
highlight Normal ctermbg=black ctermfg=green guibg=black guifg=green

" Custom highlighting for various elements (optional)
highlight Comment ctermfg=darkgreen guifg=darkgreen
highlight Constant ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight Identifier ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight Statement ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight PreProc ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight Type ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight Special ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen
highlight Underlined cterm=underline ctermfg=lightgreen guifg=lightgreen

That should do it!
:syn on and :syn off work for me.
After installing the plugins, the gruvbox color scheme should be applied automatically. If you encounter any issues, comment out the colorscheme gruvbox line in the .vimrc file by adding a " at the beginning of the line to disable it.

Thank you! So, with this approach, I will have to re-define all the highlight groups for C syntax ? or the ones in my_c_highlight will override the colors after loading default colorscheme ?

Still not working! :-( when I tried this from a slow console, I saw that for a fraction of a second, the colors set in the autocmd had taken effect but got changed .. so some other plugin/something is overriding it!  but I  am not able to make out how! I have put this block at the start of my vimrc and there are no other BufWinEnter or highlight statements!

I've updated the answer, the last line is perhaps what you should try first to see what goes on when started with verbose.

I removed all entries and just kept the block you suggested in .vimrc, still didnt help! :(
I tried the debug logs, was too much to follow!
I see that setting colorscheme desert comes somewhat close to my older settings.. for now, I think I will use it and try for a few days

Are you absolutely sure there are no windows ^M or '\r' or invisible trailing spaces or anything like that? although in 2024 it should work anyway. I managed to screw up my config while testing, but I ended up with a fancy vim. I changed my answer, I hope I am not wasting your time.

This is an older version of Ubuntu (18.04) so I am on the latest package available on that version - could be that its a buggy one. Thanks for all your help/pointers. If I am not able to adjust to these colors in a few days, I will try to manually install latest vim or try this plugin installer.
